# woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees: Update Fee on custom input change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, fee

[Image Issue Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVnDK.png)

---

#### At the WooCommerce "checkout" page:

I would like to input any number in the "**Custom Fee Input**"

- then it will be calculated in the "**Total price table**".

- After placing order the "**Custom Fee**" will be auto synchronized into the **database**.

---

*Recommendation: using **Plain JavaScript** instead of **jQuery** is highly appreciated.*

---

### This is my codes:

> html

```html
<label>
    Custom Fee
    <input id="custom_fee" name="custom_fee" type="number" required>
</label>
```

> Plain JavaScript

```js
var $custom_fee = document.getElementById("custom_fee");

$custom_fee.addEventListener("change", function(){

    var data = {
        action: 'custom_fee',
        security: wc_checkout_params.apply_state_nonce,
        custom_fee_cost: $custom_fee.value,
    };

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', wc_checkout_params.ajax_url, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    request.onload = function() {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            var resp = this.response;
            console.log(resp);
        } else {
            var resp = this.response;
            console.log(resp);
        }
    };

    request.send(data);

});
```

> function.php

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_custom_fee', 'custom_fee_ajax', 10);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_fee', 'custom_fee_ajax', 10);

function custom_fee_ajax() {
    if( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    global $wpdb;
    if( isset($_POST['custom_fee']) ){
        $custom_fee = $_POST['custom_fee'];
        WC()->session->set( 'custom_fee', $custom_fee );
        echo json_encode( WC()->session->get('custom_fee' ) );
    }
    die();
}

//________________________________________________________

add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee');

function custom_fee() {
    if( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    session_start();
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    $fee = $_SESSION['custom_fee'];
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Custom Fee' , $fee, true, '' );
}
```

---

**NOTE:** The above code does not work correctly (bad request 400; php functions); so I would like to have someone help I to solve this issue.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is every time I change the input number:
- The **custom_fee()** function show **0** price at front-end (is not changing).
- The javascript ajax response *0* and **error 400** (Bad Request).

- I've followed this [method](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-checkout-fees-based-on-radio-button-choice-ajax/) but it's not working in WooCommerce (v4.0.0)

> I haven't known how to fix it yet :(